# What is the difference between $\nabla _{\sigma} $ and $ \nabla^{\sigma}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, tensor-calculus, differentiation

What is the difference between:

$\nabla _{\sigma} $ and $ \nabla^{\sigma}$?

I've been told that the first is the covariant derivative, however I'm just starting a course on spacetime geometry and am still a bit unsure of the notation.

Answer (score 6):

$\nabla_\sigma$ is the covariant derivative. $\nabla^\sigma$ means $g^{\sigma\rho}\nabla_\rho$. It's pretty much the same as raising any other index. The covariant derivative when acting on any tensor adds a down index, and you can raise it as with any other index. Since the covariant derivative of the metric is 0, you can work with either $\nabla_\sigma$ or $\nabla^\sigma$ without worrying about derivatives of the metric showin up.

Comment: sorry, to be more precise, why does:
$\nabla^{\sigma}[\nabla_{\sigma},\nabla_{\nu}]f = 0$

Where f is a scalar?

Comment: The high-level answer is that $[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_nu]$ represents the commutator of infinitesimal parallel transport, curvature. But since a scalar is unaffected by parallel transport, the effect of curvature on it is zero. For a more pedestrian approach you can calculate it in coordinates where the Christoff symbols vanish (such coordinates always exist).

Comment: @sarahusher $\nabla_a f = \partial_a f$ for $f$ scalar.